# Why does nmap show every host is up?

Tags: networking, nmap

I've run a simple `nmap` search and every IP within my subnet are seen by `nmap` as being up but with the switches MAC address. eg:

```
Nmap scan report for 192.168.21.246
Host is up (0.0053s latency).
All 100 scanned ports on 192.168.21.246 are filtered
MAC Address: 00:00:0C:07:AC:0D (Cisco Systems)

Nmap scan report for 192.168.21.247
Host is up (0.0056s latency).
All 100 scanned ports on 192.168.21.247 are filtered
MAC Address: 00:00:0C:07:AC:0D (Cisco Systems)

Nmap scan report for 192.168.21.248
Host is up (0.0058s latency).
All 100 scanned ports on 192.168.21.248 are filtered
MAC Address: 00:00:0C:07:AC:0D (Cisco Systems)

Nmap scan report for 192.168.21.249
Host is up (0.0063s latency).
All 100 scanned ports on 192.168.21.249 are filtered
MAC Address: 00:00:0C:07:AC:0D (Cisco Systems)
```

This is a just a quick scan (`nmap -T4 -F 192.168.21.1-254`).

Is there some switch config that is spoofing the status of those IPs or is this the normal behaviour of `nmap` (it's been a while since I've last used `nmap` but I don't recall this behaviour before and unfortunately I don't have another safe network with a different stack of networking switches to test this on).

Lastly, those hosts do not respond to `ping` so I don't believe it is an issue with ICMP but this is where my networking knowledge gets a little fuzzy.

edit: for clarity, the hosts being reported as up are IPs with no host attached.

edit 2: After a little more research I've been able to determine that `nmap` is defaulting to ARP pings rather than ICMP echoes (what people often refer to as "ping"). Disabling ARP pings via the `--disable-arp-ping` flag now forces the ICMP echoes and I'm only seeing hosts being marked as "up" for IPs that literally do have a physical/virtual machine attached. So that is a step in the right direction.

**HOWEVER** some of our internal security monitoring tools exhibit the same problem as `nmap` (they possibly just use `nmap` in the background) I now need to research a way to configure our Cisco switches not to return an ARP entry for IPs without an endpoint. But that is a tangent from this StackExchange question :)

Comment: Depending on the configuration of those hosts they could easily block ping requests.

Comment: ICMP requests are enabled on our internal infrastructure. However your scenario is the inverse of the issue I'm having where IPs without an assigned host are being reported as "up".